# How to use Openfire with XMPP MUC Light

Tags: xmpp, openfire, multiuserchat

Queries Chat Service for MUC Light Support via Disco must contains it taht "" But Openfire 4.1.3 haven't this.Should l use other plugins?

Answer (score 0):

[MUC Light](https://xmpp.org/extensions/inbox/muc-light.html) is being supported by MongooseIM Team. So it's available in MongooseIM XMPP Server but not in Openfire Server.

So instead of "Other Plugins" you will have to go for other XMPP server i.e. MongooseIM.